# Obtaining full URL component within RedHat OpenShift Python3 Beginner's Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, openshift

After the first Python3 application is created in a new RedHat OpenShift account, wsgi.py looks like this template:

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    ctype = 'text/plain'
    if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/health':
        response_body = "1"
    elif environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/env':
        response_body = ['%s: %s' % (key, value)
                    for key, value in sorted(environ.items())]
        response_body = '\n'.join(response_body)
    else:
        ctype = 'text/html'

        response_body = '<lots of html>'

    response_body = response_body.encode('utf-8')
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', ctype), 
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]

    #
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [response_body ]

#
# Below for testing only
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    # Wait for a single request, serve it and quit.
    httpd.handle_request()
```

My question is this: During the execution of this code, the following information appears in the log, "[28/Jun/2016 18:35:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14". How do I get at that information from within the python program? Have examined the available variables but can not see it. Is there a function call I can make?

Many thanks for your insights.

.... later ....

From reader fat fantasma I see that I should provide additional information.

The user connects to the website using a URL that looks like this:
    http://www.website.com/help?

The "help?" appears after the GET in "GET / HTTP/1.1", when the extension to the base URL appears. The GET phrase appears in the system log but I need access to it within wsgi.py's app() function. I do not see how to do that.

Comment: Your question is unclear at least to me. What info are you getting to get?